# Splitting polygon into polygons based on data point groups using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.5, toolbox

Is there a function in ArcGIS 10.5.1 that can split a polygon (black outline) based on the location of data points (red circles)? I need it to simply make a divide in between different groups of points, which is in this case group 1 and 2 (see image).

[image]

Comment: No, but you can create Thiessen polygons https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00080000001m000000, spatial join your points and dissolve by your point values. I think that will approximate your diagram but will not reach all the way to the edges of the black polygon, you can use polygon neighbors to transpose the values to the edges.

Comment: @MichaelStimson I'm thinking Join Fields rather than Spatial Join to get polygon attributes from the points because I think Thiessen Polygons get the ID of their points.  I like the idea of using Polygon Neighbors to help fill any gaps around the edge.

Answer (score 4):

This is untested but I would try this workflow:

1. Run [Thiessen Polygons](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/business-analyst-toolbox/thiessen-polygons.htm) to create polygons from your points
2. Clip the result using your black polygon, if necessary
3. Dissolve using the field that stores the group values

Comment: That worked brilliantly! Thank you. 
How should I use "Polygon Neighbors" to help fill the gap?

Comment: I think you should ask another question, linking it back to this one, and describe precisely the procedure that you used and where you are stuck with filling in the gap(s).

Comment: I manged to sort it, in "create thiessen polygons" i changed "processing extent" - "Extent" to the outer polygon